# R: Conditionally Replace Lat/Lons with Values from Shape File (Point in Polygon Analysis)

Tags: r, dataframe, coordinates, point-in-polygon, centroid

I'm doing a point in polygon analysis to replace lat/lons that = 0 with county centroid lat/lons from a shape file. Forgive me if this question seems trivial, but I'm new to R and my solutions haven't seemed to work out nor have I found very similar questions on here.

Here's an example of what Table A looks like:

```
ID | Lat | Lon | State_FIPS | County_FIPS 
------------------------------------------
1  |  33 | -88 |    028     |    087
2  |  31 | -98 |    048     |    225
3  |  0  |  0  |    017     |    034
4  | 39  | -100|    020     |    063
```

Then I have the county shape file, which includes stateFIPS, countyFIPS, and lat/lons. Here's what I have so far:

```
#get shape file 
zfn <-  "tl_2010_us_county10_simplified"
cns.shp <- readOG(".", zfn)

#create spdf from table A 
a.df <- a.spdf

#make lat/lon into coordinates
coordinates(a.spdf) = ~LON+LAT

#set to same projection as shape file
proj4string(a.spdf) <- proj4string(cns.shp)

#point in polygon analysis
events.in <- over(as(a.spdf, "SpatialPoints"), as(cns.shp, "SpatialPolygons"))
a.spdf$LAT = cns.shp$INTPTLAT10[events.in]
a.spdf$LON = cns.shp$INTPTLON10[events.in]
a.df <- as.data.frame(a.spdf)
```

INTPTLAT10 and INTPTLON10 are the lat/lon centroids from the shape file.

There's a couple problems here:

**1) The following code generates an error because LAT/LON are coordinates.**

```
a.spdf$LAT = cns.shp$INTPTLAT10[events.in]
a.spdf$LON = cns.shp$INTPTLON10[events.in]
```

The error I'm receiving is below:

```
Error in `$<-`(`*tmp*`, "LAT", value = c(657L, 1787L, 338L, 859L, 901L, : 
LAT is a coordinate name, please choose another name.
```

Is it possible to replace these values? Do I have to change them back from coordinates?

**2) I'm not sure how to specify that I only want to replace the LAT/LON values that are equal to 0.**

Would this be an ifelse statement? Assuming I can somehow fix the coordinate error, would it look something like this?

```
a[a.spdf$LAT == 0] <- cns.shp$INTPTLAT10[events.in]
a[a.spdf$LON == 0] <- cns.shp$INTPTLON10[events.in]
```

I'm sure there are plenty of errors in my code, again R is very new to me. Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated, I have been stuck on this all day!

Comment: You need `==`, which tests equality, in 2, not `=`, which assigns. Also, you probably need a comma to specify you're subsetting rows, and specify the columns.

Comment: Thank you! Editing that now.

Comment: Make smaller questions, incude data as `dput`, only ask one question

Comment: Sorry, still figuring this site out. Maybe I'll create a 2nd post to separate the questions.